# Finality lagging

Tags: grandpa, finality

After about 50 blocks my block production slows down because none of the nodes are voting in the finality rounds. I'm working off a codebase that I added the grandpa pallet to, so it's possible I may have screwed something up in the setup, but I can't figure out what it is. Where should I check to make sure I'm doing everything right? Things I've already checked:

- The grandpa RPC is initialized.
- The nodes have the right keys set.
- fg_primitives::GrandpaApi is implemented in the runtime.
- pallet_grandpa::Config is connected to the right stuff.

What have I missed, and is there anywhere I can check to see why the voting isn't happening?

Comment: Please share your source yo get support, otherwise it will be very very difficult to if at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanShields I don't I can do that. But there must be things I can check myself against the Substrate node.

Comment: debug logs? need something concrete to work on.